# Distributed Streaming Applications (Graph and Transaction) In Reallife

Tags: distributed-computing, stream-processing

I am currently studying distributed stream processing systems, e.g. Storm, Flink and Spark Streaming. I want to implement some applications in these systems and briefly compare them. I wonder if there is any company using these systems for processing the following situations and what's the scale of the data stream.

1. **Graph** where a large graph may be distributed to multiple machines and we handles some updates (add or remove vertices or edges) and queries on the graph. So far I can only find some streaming graph algorithms on a single machine.
2. **Transaction** where exactly-once message delivery is a must. There exists a *Leaderboard Maintenance Benchmark* in S-Store (Meehan, John, et al. "S-store: Streaming meets transaction processing." Proceedings of the VLDB Endowment 8.13 (2015): 2134-2145) but I cannot find how they generated the input data.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [yahoo's benchmark](https://github.com/yahoo/streaming-benchmarks)  for comparing Apache Storm, Apache Spark, Apache Flink and Apache Apex etc

Comment: Thanks. However, as I have checked the repo, there is only one application which doesn't fall into the above two categories.